# Is it possible to make the use of unnecessary semicolons a compile-time warning/error?

Tags: swift

I've worked so much in C and Objective-C that I keep writing semicolons at the end of my Swift lines. This is really starting to annoy me, as it seems like a bad practice in this language;

Is it possible to make [Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) flag this as an error or a warning so that I can kick the habit?

Comment: I'd at least like to see them syntax highlighted in a nasty colour :) And unnecessary parentheses around if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but it came up recently:

https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint

Heaven forbid though, you could just do a single search of your project

Cmd-Shift-Option-F (which is possible if you are left handled and play guitar).